# Why is my answer, which basically says the same thing as the upvoted answer, downvoted?

Tags: discussion, downvotes

Earlier, I saw a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37904351/java-member-object-allocated-in-constructor-destroyed/37904384#37904384) and I answered it. It seems like a careless mistake made by a beginner. So I explained the mistake to the OP in great detail.

Then I went out for a while. After I came back, I saw that my answer got one upvote and one downvote. I didn't understand why because I rarely encounter this. However, the other answer, which basically says the same thing as mine but in less detail, got 2 upvotes. I *really* don't understand.

After a while, the question got closed as a duplicate. And today, I see my answer being downvoted again! The other answer also got a downvote too.

I am not saying that the downvote should be reverted or anything like that. I just want to know *why* the user thought my answer is wrong or low quality.

I think that since the question is a duplicate, people are thinking,

> Ah this guy must have copied an answer from that duplicate question! I gotta downvote this since this is probably not his own answer.

This is just my guess but, am I right?

If I am, should we educate people not to think answers are copied from duplicates unless they only differ by a few words? Because I didn't even know that's a duplicate when I post the answer.

Comment: Since downvotes are anonymous you have no way of knowing what the voter was thinking. Chalk it up to experience and move on.

Comment: FYI, the *accepted* answer has a score breakdown of +3 / -2.

Comment: The right thing would have been to search for a duplicate and vote to close. I can imagine some people think that's what you should have done and have voted accordingly. Of course as voting is anonymous we'll never know will we.

Comment: So i fail to see what we can do here.... You think we can a)track down WHO voted...  And b) use SO's patented mind reader to know? If it's a dupe... Then it's possible you got DVed simply for answering it, as it was arguably something that should've been closed instead.

Comment: What I want to ask here is why I often see answers often down voted on duplicate and/or closed questions, even though they're not low quality and are correct.

Comment: @Sweeper a lot of quality minded users are vocal about closed questions not belonging on the site, and how these questions even getting ONE answer is not helpful to the goal of Stack. So some people seem to downvote these on principle.

Comment: @Patrice ok I see. But only a small group of people think like this, right?

Comment: @Sweeper hard to tell. I've seen some people on meta mention it. A couple of questions here and there about it as well. In general, in a question like the one you linked... I would potentially DV most answers, as it's CLEAR that there is a dupe of this somewhere....

Comment: @Sweeper You're still stuck with your answer that is a downvote lure. Perhaps what you really want to know is what to do with your answer?

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer was posted before your answer.  Your answer now has more votes.

It is also a duplicate and as a regular on the site, if another regular saw it as a duplicate and that you answered it, it *may* have been the reason for the downvote, as some people downvote answers to duplicates, rather than the user voting to close.

This is a guess.

[image]